# Stepping through code from console application into wcf web service

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I created a wcf service in a solution and a console project in the same solution

I hosted my wcf service in IIS and makes a call to the uri in console application

From my wcf application I did a right click on the project,selected debug and then 
selected start new instance

I set breakpoints in my console application and in the first method that gets hit
in my student.svc.cs file

I went to windows explorer and double clicked my console application executable

I am able to step through from my student.svc.cs file but the breakpoint on my console 
application does not get hit.

I want to be able to step through code from my console app then to the webservice
but this is not happening

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the "right" project (bin folder in this case). You can set the console app to start project and set the wcf service to start on debug (options), then you can step through from your console app to the service.

Comment: Thanks. When you say start on debug(options), am I doing this from the options menu item?